# How to implement Kalman filter when state vector contains observable and unobservable variables?

Tags: time-series

The problem is as follows: in a state space model:

\begin{align}
S(t) &= A * S(t-1) + u(t) \\
Z(t) &= B * S(t) + v(t)
\end{align}

where $S(t)$ is a vector process containing $4$ variables but only the last $2$ variables are unobservable, $Z(t)$ contains $6$ observable variables. I know if the $4$ variables in $S(t)$ are all unobservable, then we can use Kalman filter to estimate the model and to filter out $S(t)$. But in my setup, can I still use Kalman filter to estimate and to filter out the only $2$ unobservable variables in $S(t)$? If yes, do I need to modify the algorithm and how?

Many thanks in advance!